# Python: extend python subplots() over mutirow/multicolumn

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-columns, subplot

I need to pass a matplotlib subplot instance as variable of a function.
I cannot make it work when it's a multicolumn/multirow subplot.

I would like to achieve this result:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xx = np.linspace(-1,1)

grid = plt.GridSpec(3, 3)

plt.subplot(grid[0:2,0:2]).plot(xx, xx**1)
plt.subplot(grid[2,1:3]).plot(xx, xx**2)
plt.subplot(grid[0:2,2]).plot(xx, xx**3)
plt.subplot(grid[2,0]).plot(xx, xx**4)
```

[image: subfigures extended over more columns/rows]

while passing each subfigure as an argument of this function:

```py
def fill_subplot( x, y, ax ):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    sub_plt = ax.plot( x, y )
    return sub_plt
```

I can get this to work without multirows/multicolumns:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex='col', sharey='row')

for ii in range(3):
    fill_subplot(xx, ii*xx*0, ax[ii,0])
    fill_subplot(xx, ii*xx*1, ax[ii,1])
    fill_subplot(xx, ii*xx*2, ax[ii,2])
```

[image]

But when I try to combine the two (either by passing the GridSpec object as an argument or by slicing the subplots() ) I get the following errors:

```py
grid = plt.GridSpec(3, 3, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3)

fill_subplot(xx, xx*0, grid[ii,0:2])
```

gives  `AttributeError: 'SubplotSpec' object has no attribute 'plot'`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, sharex='col', sharey='row')

ax[0:2,0].plot(xx, xx**0)
```

gives `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'`

How can I make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: In the first case you use an actual subplot (`plt.subplot(grid[0:2,0:2])`), in the second case you use only the gridspec (`grid[0:2,0:2]`). Pass the subplot, just as in the first case and it will work.

Comment: I actually keep getting a   "Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes " warning. I am using:
```ax = fig.add_subplot(grid[count,0])```
```fill_subplot(xx, xx*0, ax)```

Comment: This condensed code sample does not allow me to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the explanation

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xx = np.linspace(-1,1)

grid = plt.GridSpec(3, 3)

fill_subplot(xx, xx**1, plt.subplot(grid[0:2,0:2]))
fill_subplot(xx, xx**2, plt.subplot(grid[2,1:3]))
fill_subplot(xx, xx**3, plt.subplot(grid[0:2,2]))
fill_subplot(xx, xx**4, plt.subplot(grid[2,0]))
```

[image]